# React Todo list. form input not dissapearing after onsumbit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for the life of me, i do not know why my react app isn't working. My input state get's rendered after onSubmit. but my value isn't disappearing in my input bar. and nothing is being render on my list. I've only had this problem after breaking my components to smaller chunks, i had no problem making this work when it was 1 whole component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      input: '',
      items: []
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      input: '',
      items: [...this.state.items,this.state.input]
    })
    console.log(this.state.input)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        value={this.state.input}/>
        <List items={this.state.items}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.input}/>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.items.map((item,index) => {
            <li key={index}>{item}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Not disappearing" problem is because of that:

```
<input onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.input}/>
```

There isn't any `input` prop, it is `value`. See:

```
value={this.state.input}
```

So it should be:

```
<input onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.value}/>
```

Listing problem is because of this:

```
{
    this.props.items.map((item,index) => {
        <li key={index}>{item}</li>
    })
}
```

Here, you are using an arrow function and a body block. If you use a body block you have to use a `return` statement.

```
{
  this.props.items.map( ( item, index ) => {
    return ( <li key={index}>{item}</li> );
  } )
}
```

or you can use it like this:

```
{
  this.props.items.map( ( item, index ) =>
    <li key={index}>{item}</li> )
}
```